# How do I get request input in route closure?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I just finished reading *Request* chapter. And I want to know how to get request input in route closure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a object of `Illuminate\Http\Request;`

```
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) {
        $request->all();
    });
```

Or

```
Route::get('/', function () {    
    Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::all();
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a global helper:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    request()->id;
});
```